# Yarn: error `install` has been replaced with `add` but it won't run add command either

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby-on-rails, ruby, yarnpkg

I'm on Ubuntu. Rails 6 project. I'm trying to add new packages to my project but it won't accept the `yarn install` nor `yarn add` commands.

I tried adding `flatpìckr` using `yarn install flatpickr` and it prompted me to use the `add` command instead

```
yarn install flatpickr
yarn install v1.22.17
error `install` has been replaced with `add` to add new dependencies. Run "yarn add flatpickr" instead.
```

However, I get the same message when running the `add` command:

```
yarn add flatpickr
yarn install v1.22.17
error `install` has been replaced with `add` to add new dependencies. Run "yarn add flatpickr" instead.
```

I'm running the latest version of Yarn and I can succesfully run commands like `yarn install --checkfiles`, I just can't seem to add new ones.

Comment: Are you trying to install the specific version 1.22.17 of flatpickr? You might be looking for the `yarn add [package_name]@[version]` command [from the docs here.](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/managing-dependencies). So you would enter `yarn add flatpickr@1.22.17` or `yarn upgrade flatpickr@1.22.17` if you're upgrading.